# How to fix Memory Leak in Custom WifiStatus file in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Please suggest how to fix below memory leak.

[image: WifiStatus.m File]

**Note**: I am using ARC in my Project. It is compiled using ARC only.

I tried to take temporary dict and BOOL and then return those variables. But still memory leak doesn't fix...

Thanks in Advance...!

[image: Status]

[image: wifi connection]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should do it, this passes

> XCode Menu: "Product" >> "Analyze"

This is showing ZERO potential or realized memory leaks:

```
-(BOOL)isWifiConnected {
    return wifiDetails() == nil ? NO : YES;
}

NSDictionary *wifiDetails() {
    CFArrayRef interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    CFDictionaryRef captiveNtwrkDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(interfaces, 0));
    NSDictionary *dict = ( __bridge_transfer NSDictionary*) captiveNtwrkDict;
    CFRelease(interfaces);
    return dict;
}
```

Comment: ThanQ..It fixes the memory leaks. Sorry for delay.